# $.getJSON return array object has special characters

Tags: json

My coding returns the json array and the object has special characters which i am not able to retrieve the data in my coding.

Example:

```
{ "No."         : "3",
  "sign"        : "positive",
  "nr_old"      : "",
  "referring domain or url":"www.google.co.za",
  "visits"      : "1",
  "avg. pv/ v"  :"4.0",
  "graph"       : ""
}
```

In the above example, i am not able to retrieve "No." and "referring domain or url" and "avg. pv/ v"

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to use bracket notation to access the property:

```
var value = obj['No.']; // obj['referring domain or url'], etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

```
data = {
  "No."         : "3",
  "sign"        : "positive",
  "nr_old"      : "",
  "referring domain or url":"www.google.co.za",
  "visits"      : "1",
  "avg. pv/ v"  :"4.0",
  "graph"       : ""
}

data['No.']                        // '3'
data['avg. pv/ v']                 // '4.0'
data['referring domain or url']    // 'www.google.co.za'
```